# Linear vs smooth actions of finite groups on spheres, Euclidean spaces and closed disks

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, reference-request, geometric-topology

I would like to know examples (with references, if possible) of the following:

(1) a finite group $G$ acting effectively and smoothly on a sphere $S^n$ but admitting no effective linear action on $S^n$ (so $G$ is not isomorphic to any subgroup of $O(n+1,\mathbb{R})$);

(2) a finite group $G$ acting effectively and smoothly on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (any $n$) but admitting no effective action on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by affine transformations;

(3) a finite group $G$ acting effectively and smoothly on the closed $n$-dimensional disk $D^n$ (any $n$), but admitting no effective linear action on $D^n$ (so $G$ is not isomorphic to any subgroup of $O(n,{\mathbb R})$).

Some comments on these questions:

A paper of Petrie ("Free metacyclic group actions on
homotopy spheres") gives an example of finite group acting *freely* on a sphere $S^n$ but admitting no *free* linear action on $S^n$.

For $p$-groups, there are no examples of (1) and (3), by a theorem of Dotzel and Hamrick.

An example of (3) is automatically an example of (2), since a finite group of affine transformations of ${\mathbb R}^n$ fixes a point and hence can be identified with a finite subgroup of $O(n)$.

There are in the litterature several results implying that there are no low dimensional examples of (1), (2) and (3).